# Calculating and displaying the time difference between two date/time fields in hours and minutes

Tags: apex, datetime

I am getting the difference in time between two date/time fields. I need to show the time in hours:minutes in another field.

```
Long timeOpen = BusinessHours.diff(bh.Id, ar.Date_Time_Assigned__c, ar.Completed_Canceled_Date_Time__c);
Long seconds = timeOpen / 1000;
Long minutes = seconds / 60;
Long hours = minutes / 60;
ar.Time_Open__c = hours;
```

Right now, I'm only getting the hours, but I need to include the minutes too.

Comment: What is the field type of "Time_Open__c"?

Comment: Last time I checked, `minutes = seconds * 60` and `hours = minutes * 60`. Did you perhaps mean to put `minutes = timeOpen / 60` or were you looking to get the `integerValue` of `timeOpen / 60` and then use the remainder to do your calculations with for `minutes`, and similarly for `seconds`, etc?

Comment: Meant to add that the remainder would be the `mod`. See Math Methods in the Apex Code Developer's Guide for more.

Comment: If you dont need to do it via apex, I recommend looking at this which was accomplished via formula. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50130/difference-between-2-datetime-fields-in-hours-and-minutes-with-timezones

Answer (score 1):

If you look at my answer to the following question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42331/how-to-calculate-the-time-between-two-datetimes/51061#51061), I created a very simple time difference utility to return the time difference between two `Time` instances or two `DateTime` instances.

From there you can extend the utility with the following to get what you want:

```
public static String GetHourAndMinuteDisplay(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return GetElapsedTime(startDate, endDate).format('hh:mm');
}
```

If you need to get hours or minutes separately, it's rather straight-forward.

For hours:

```
public static Integer GetElapsedHours(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return GetElapsedTime(startDate, endDate).hour();
}
```

For minutes:

```
public static Integer GetElapsedMinutes(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return GetElapsedTime(startDate, endDate).minute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula to get the correct answer of ur question:
It will return hour, min, sec and AM or PM
Datetime.now().format('hh:mm:ss a');